# How dispatch_once works in a category in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Hello i am new to objective c. I created a category in objective c. I used `dispatch_once` to define the Custom UIColor.

Check the code below.

```
#import "UIColor+CustomColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (CustomColors)

- (UIColor *)GetCustomColorLightYellowBGColor {

    static UIColor *lightYellowBGColor;
    
    //use dispatch_once_t pointer predicate to check if the block has finished
    //A pointer to a dispatch_once_t structure that is used to test whether the block has completed or not
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        lightYellowBGColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0 / 255.0
                                           green:230.0 / 255.0
                                            blue:54.0 / 255.0
                                           alpha:1.0];
    });

    return lightYellowBGColor;
}

@end
```

dispatch_once documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once mentions the following

*This function is useful for initialization of global data (singletons) in an application. Always call this function before using or testing any variables that are initialized by the block.*

So i initialize the Custom UIColor Class and then i use the

```
self.view.backgroundColor = customColorClass.CustomColorLightYellowBGColor;
```

Color changes correctly on the view so everything is ok.

I want to ask the following.

If i use again on purpose `self.view.backgroundColor = customColorClass.GetCustomColorLightYellowBGColor;`

Will dispatch_once initialise the UIColor again or because is a singleton initialisation will not initialise the UIColor? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_once()` works the same no matter what compilation unit it is in.  So, yes, it will initialize `lightYellowBGColor` exactly once.

Note that the method name `GetCustomColorLightYellowBGColor` really should be just `customColorLightYellowBGColor` and it should be a class method, not an instance method, as you don't need to instantiate a UIColor to have the method work.

Better, it shouldn't be a category on `UIColor` at all.  While convenient, categories lead to messy code because you are effectively interleaving your app specific code with the framework code.

A typical pattern for this sort of thing would be to have a `MyAppConfiguration` class or something that contains a bunch of methods for retrieving configuration items like this.   This also lays the easy foundation for allowing the user to customize the app's configuration and/or presentation by pooling all the configurable items in one place.

Comment: But how i am going to get the method from the Main View Controller if its a class method? I get Property 'GetCustomColorLightYellowBGColor' not found on object of type 'UIColor *' when i use self.view.backgroundColor = self.color.GetCustomColorLightYellowBGColor

Comment: found it. you can call the class method from another class like this  self.view.backgroundColor = [self.color WeAre8ColorLightYellowBGColor]; thanks for the suggestion